# Cross Browser Proper Sizing for Responsive Images as Checkbox/Radio Button

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a quiz with images as placeholders for the check buttons and radio buttons.

Those are all working fine except for the padding.

In Safari and Chrome, I am having no issues. Firefox is not calculating the sizes of each correctly.

Here is a jsfiddle example of what is happening.

Here is the css I use to make the images responsive.
    .quiz img {
        max-width:100% !important;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        margin: auto;
    }

There are 10 pictures total, so I intended to have two rows of 5 on each. (on the actual site, there are media queries to adjust to other devices)

```
.questionOneO {
width: 20%;
float: left;    
}
```

This is the CSS I'm using to replace the radio buttons with images.

```
.quiz input[type="radio"]{
display:none;
}
.quiz input[type="radio"] + label {
background: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.quiz input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
background: #ef529d;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/35DTq/6/

On the actual site, in firefox, the images all fit in the container but the padding doesn't appear to be calculated correctly despite using "box-sizing: border-box;" and "-moz-box-sizing: border-box;"

In the jsfiddle example, it looks even worse.

What can I do to make this work on Firefox as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix, the problem is the label element has no width restrictions, the image expands to fill the label and the label seems to randomly choose a size....

Fix is to add the following css

`.quiz label {
    max-width:100%;
}`

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8FG7j/